# How to count the number of alphabetic literals in a String?

Tags: java, string, count

Currently I have a simple problem to solve:
Given a `String str`, what is the best way of counting the amount of alphabetic literals in the string?

Right now I am thinking something like this:

```
int letterCount = 0;
for(int i = 0 : str){
    String check = "" + str.charAt(i);
        if(check.isLetter())
            letterCount++
}
```

Are there any more efficient or elegant ways?

Comment: [Count letters in a String : Character « Data Type « Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/CountlettersinaString.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m pretty fond of streams (since Java 8):

```
    String str = "A string";

    long letterCount = str.chars().filter(Character::isLetter).count();
    System.out.println(letterCount);
```

> 7

Your `for` loop is another nice solution. Here’s a version that works:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < str.length(); index++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(str.charAt(index))) {
            letterCount++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "#CodeWines65"; 
int upper = 0, lower = 0, number = 0, special = 0; 

for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
    { 
        char ch = str.charAt(i); 
        if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') 
            upper++; 
        else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') 
            lower++; 
        else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') 
            number++; 
        else
            special++; 
    } 

System.out.println("Lower case letters : " + lower); 
System.out.println("Upper case letters : " + upper); 
System.out.println("Number : " + number); 
System.out.println("Special characters : " + special);
```

// If you are not concerned about uppercase or lowercase you can add them both & get the total count

Comment: “Årets æblehøst” is Danish for “this year’s apple harvest”. You aren’t counting all of the letters in that string… Even for English I don’t hesitate to recommend `Character.isLetter` over use of `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: Adding lower & upper will obviously give the total count of letters in the string

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to think of a solution. While I chose another answer, I am sure someone will find your version helpful. :)